# Difficulty Sending Numbers from Arduino to Python via Serial Data

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, raspberry-pi, byte

I am trying to write a program that will send serial data from an Arduino to a Python program running on a raspberry pi. I have encountered an issue when sending numbers greater 9. When I send a number greater than 9, the python program only interprets the first digit in the number. 5 for 563, 9 for 9135, 4 for 43, etc... Any help to resolve this issue would be appreciated. Thanks.

Arduino Code:

```
int First=2;
int buttonState=0;
int num = 0;

void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(First, INPUT);  

}

void loop()
{
 int buttonState=digitalRead(First);

 if(buttonState==HIGH&&(num==1))
 {
   Serial.print(549);
   num--;
   delay(500);
   buttonState = 0;
 }
 if(buttonState==HIGH&&(num==0))
 {
   Serial.print(74);
   num++;
   delay(500);
   buttonState = 0;
 }
 if(buttonState==LOW)
 {
   //do nothing
 }
}
```

Python Code:

```
import numpy
import cv2, glob
import sys
import os
import keyboard
import serial

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import time

keyboard = Controller()
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB3',9600)

while True:
    command = ser.read()
    if command:
        ser.flushInput()
        print("new command:", command)
        if(int(command) == 74):
            time.sleep(2)
            keyboard.press(Key.space)
            keyboard.release(Key.space)
```

Basically, the problem is that when I hit the button, 74 will be sent from the Arduino, yet the python program only recognizes it as 7. As a result, only 7 gets output to the screen. Is there any way to have the python program recognize the entire number, not just the first digit?

Comment: You do not send the number 74, but the text "7459474594..." interrupted  by some delays.

Comment: He converts it to an integer in the if statement `int(command)`

Answer (score 0):

[stream.read()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/read) only returns the first byte of incoming data, that is, a char in this case. You should use [stream.readBytes()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readbytes/) or [stream.readString()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/readstring/) instead. They read the data until the end has been reached or the function times out. Here is an exemple of code I used to read integers with multiple digits:

```
int getInt()
{
  // Create an empty string
  String val = "";

  // While the string is empty...
  while(val == "")
  {
    // ... wait for the user to enter a string
    val = Serial.readString();
  }

  // Return the string converted to an integer
  return val.toInt();  
}
```